# spark + python + filter issue

Tags: python, apache-spark, filter, word-count

Appreciate if someone can shed some light on below code snippet issue

```
lineStr= sc.textFile("/input/words.txt")
print (lineStr.collect())
['this file is created to count the no of texts', 'other wise i am just doing fine', 'lets see the output is there']

wc = lineStr.flatMap(lambda l: l.split(" ")).map(lambda x: (x,1)).reduceByKey(lambda w,c: w+c)
print (wc.glom().collect())
[[('this', 1), ('there', 1), ('i', 1), ('texts', 1), ('just', 1), ('fine', 1), ('is', 2), ('other', 1), ('created', 1), ('count', 1), ('of', 1), ('am', 1), ('no', 1), ('output', 1)], [('lets', 1), ('see', 1), ('the', 2), ('file', 1), ('doing', 1), ('wise', 1), ('to', 1)]]
```

Now when i am trying to filter the above data set for count values more than 1 using below, i am getting error

```
s = wc.filter(lambda a,b:b>1)
print (s.collect())
```

> error :   vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
>
> TypeError: () missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't unpack a tuple in a `lambda` function, `lambda a, b:` means a function that takes two arguments, not a function that takes a tuple as an argument:

A simple fix is to capture the element with a single argument, and then use index to access the second element in the tuple:

```
wc.filter(lambda t: t[1] > 1).collect()
# [('is', 2), ('the', 2)]
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the logic behind as well. It worked fine.